# ASP.NET Membership.FindUsersByName not working. Can't search for users. 404's

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I use this action and go to Profile/Username, it gives me a 404 even though the name exists.  I've used Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline().ToString();  and that works just fine, returning the amount of users online correctly.  I understand that if this code worked properly, it would just return a basic webpage, but it's not even doing that, I get a 404.  What gives?  Help is greatly appreciated! :)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Security;


   namespace MvcMicroBlog.Controllers
   {
        public class ProfileController : Controller
       {
           //
           // GET: /Profile/

            public ActionResult Index(string Profile)
            {
                Membership.FindUsersByName(Profile);
                return View();
            }

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a custom route defined, you should go to /Profile/?Profile=username, or you can rename your Profile parameter to id.

If you prefer the custom route approach, you can add this to your RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax.cs, before the Default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    string.Empty,
    "Profile/{Profile}",
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: Wow, another silly mistake.  I really appreciate it Tuan.  I don't know how I missed that.  But you say there is a way so that I can rename the parameter, so I can just go Profile/Username?

Comment: You're very welcome. I've edited the answer to include the custom route.